# Which Hibernate jar version should I use for jdk 1.8 and eclipse mars2?

Tags: hibernate

My question is when I use JDk1.8 with eclipse mars 2 ,for run Hibarnate ,Then same coding style I used with Netbeans ,I used it in eclipse ,but the problem is when i run this then it gives me exception could not parse Hibernate.cfg.xml .when I turn on my net connection then run fine ,but without internet connection it gives me same exception.I asked for this question but many said that use hibernate jar for jdk 1.8 version bt when I use hibernate 5 jar I gotta confuse because in that jar lot of jars are present in different folder ,so please help me out .how can i solve this problem

Comment: Hibernate jar should not force you to be online. Maybe the db you are connecting to is remote. Sharing the exception you are getting would help.

Comment: No I am not using any sharing resource or else am just simply creating an app say simply insert into database with the help of hibernate but using same in netbeans I can run it fine

Comment: Logs are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/getting-started/)

> Hibernate 5.2 and later versions require at least **Java 1.8** and JDBC 4.2.
>
> Hibernate 5.1 and older versions require at least **Java 1.6** and JDBC 4.0.
>
> When building Hibernate 5.1 or older from sources, you need Java 1.7 due to a bug in the JDK 1.6 compiler.

Comment: And for hibernate 3 or 4 versions which jdk requires?

Comment: Hibernate 5.1 and older (3.x or 4.x) requires at least jdk 1.6

Comment: @AbassA +1, this has cleared my confusion on the version support for Hibernate and Java combination